# What template file is used by default for posts?

Tags: posts, loop

So I'm attempting to create a single page Wordpress theme and right now I'm using my index.php as the page they will initially see.

In my index.php I use The Loop to create a bunch of `a` tags that link to the all of the post permalinks.

What is the template file that I need to make or what do I need to define so that I can control what those posts look like once you travel to their permalink?

Answer (score 0):

You can create new template php file.

```
//Template Name : Single Page Template
get_header();
if ( have_posts() ) : 
     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
         the_content(); 
         the_permalink();//this is for the <a> bunch you are looking for
     endwhile; 
endif;
get_footer();
```

Here , you can use "//" or "/**   **/" to set the Template name , it varies from the theme you are using.
and then , go to Add New Page and there on the right sidebar , you can choose this template , by default it was set "Default Template".
There on dropdown , you can find the newly created template file named "Single Page Template".

Answer (score -1):

For those that come here looking for an understanding of the template hierarchy, it's best to start at the Codex: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Lots of resources via the googles on building themes, including the Codex.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. The user answered his own question. I just added the link/info that would help them understand template hierarchy. Although, if one were to be picky, perhaps it is more a comment than an answer. So I suppose the downvoter is being picky....

Answer (score -3):

Nvm, found it. It's single.php.